# How can I build bottom side menu to use react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHnTR.png)

I'm not good at react But I have to assignment item this semester.
I want make side menu like that. What should I do? Is that non-modal or Hamburger menu?

Comment: take a look at this https://ant.design/components/menu/ this library

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.